# Flutter NetworkImage takes too long to load

Tags: flutter, dart

So i'm trying to load close to a thousand gifs on Inkwell widgets with a Hero child in a boxdecoration imagenetwork, i want to understand the best practice to handle this, as it takes long times to load, i want it to load by the first one to appear, whether it's normal or by filtering, so how do flutter devs handle this ?

So how do i support slow internet users by deciding which NetworkImage to load first

```
      InkWell(
      onTap: (){
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context)=>GifDetail(
          gifs: gifs,
        )));
      },
      child: Hero(
        tag: gifs.url,
        child: Card(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: 110,
                width: 110,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(image: NetworkImage(gifs.url))
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try using Cached_network_image package. It will still take the same time to load images initially but then the images are retained on the device so will load a lot quicker the next time. There is really no way of getting around the initial download of the image.

Loading via a ListView.builder or GridView.builder will only load the images in the initial view until you scroll, so should also help.